# Can I use NSStream, NSInputStream, and NSOutputStream to send and receive data from a C# application?

Tags: c#, .net, iphone, ios

Can I use `NSStream`,`NSInputStream`, and `NSOutputStream` to send and receive data from a C# application or service? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Apple's CocoaEcho or SimpleNetworkStreams sample code projects should get you started.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CocoaEcho/Introduction/Intro.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleNetworkStreams/Introduction/Intro.html